# working with temporary table in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, temp-tables, cakephp-3.2

I'm working in CakePHP 3.2

I have a table `Carts` to store products in cart when user is logged in with `user_id`.

I want addToCart accessible to user without login too. But in this case I want to use temporary table to store the cart data and when user is logged in, transfer all data from temporary table to `carts` table and delete `temporary table`.

How to work with temporary table in CakePHP 3 ? Is it a good practice to use temporary data for the same or is there any better alternative to this ?

> Edit 2

Values to store in cookie/temp table

```
product_id
seller_id
seller_product_id
quantity
```

**Associations**

`product_id` is foreign key to `products` table
`seller_id` is foreign key to `sellers` table
`seller_product_id` is foreign key to `seller_products` table

product table is further associated with `product_attributes`

Currently using `carts` table with following columns

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------------+--------+
|  user_id   | product_id  | seller_id | seller_product_id  |quantity |
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------------+--------+
```

and this is what I'm doing to retrieve associated data

```
if (!empty($this->Auth->user('id'))) {
              $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

              $g_cart = $this->Carts->find('all', [
                'conditions' => [
                  'user_id' => $user_id,
                ],
                'contain' => [
                  'Products', 'SellerProducts', 'Sellers', 'CartAttributes'
                ]
              ]);
              $g_count = $g_cart->count();

              if (!empty($g_cart)) {
//                foreach($g_cart as $g_c){debug($g_c);}
                  foreach($g_cart as $g_c) {
                    $total_cost += $g_c->quantity * $g_c->seller_product->selling_price;
                  }
              }
          }
```

Hope I'm clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in cookies for guests then transfer the cookie data into table when they login.

---

I have not tested this but it should get the ball rolling

On the method where cart items are added:

```
$cart = $this->Cookie->read('Cart.items');
if(!$this->Auth->user()) {
    if(!empty($cart)) {
        $newItem = [
            'Products' => $product->id,
            'Sellers' => $seller->id,
            'SellerProducts' => $sellerProduct->id,
            'quantity' => $quantity
        ];
        $newCart = array_merge($cookie, [$newItem]);
        $this->Cookie->write('Cart', ['items' => $newCart]);
    }else{
        $this->Cookie->write('Cart', [
            'items' => [
                'products' => $product->id,
                'sellers' => $seller->id,
                'seller_products' => $sellerProduct->id,
                'quantity' => $quantity
            ]
        ]);

    }

}else{
    $item = $this->Cart->newEntity();
    if(!empty($cart)) {
        foreach($cart as $items) {
            $data = [
                'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
                'product_id' => $items['Products'],
                'seller_id' => $items['Sellers'],
                'seller_product_id' => $items['SellerProducts'],
                'quantity' => $items['quantity']
            ];
            $item = $this->Cart->patchEntity($item, $data);
            $this->Cart->save($item);
        }
        $this->Cookie->delete('Cart.items');
    }
}
```

on CartController view method

```
$cart = $this->Cookie->read('Cart');    
$entities = [];

if(!$this->Auth->user() && !empty($cart) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($cart['items'] as  $items) {
        foreach($items as $model => $id) {
            if($model == 'quantity') {
                $quantity = $id;
                continue;
            }
            $this->loadModel($model);
            $entity = $this->$model->get($id, ['contain' => []]);
            $entities[$i][] = $entity;
            $entities[$i]['quantity'] = $quantity;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $this->set('items', $entities);
}
```

On the view.ctp for CartController

```
if(!empty($items)) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        foreach($item as $entity) {
            echo '<div><?=$entity->name</div>';
            echo '<div><?=$entity->quantity</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but the problem is how could I fetch associated data with cookie. because I'm storing only primary keys to cookie.

Comment: I can try to help you out, how are your databases setup and what are the associations?

Comment: edited...not tested but it should give you the gist of it.